# Where can I find a list of players' fantasy points for TI3?

Tags: dota-2

I am unable to find any ranking on the internet where I can see standings for fantasy teams points of currently running The International Dota 2 championship. I've only seen some threads like [this](http://forum.gamesports.net/dota/showthread.php?55065-Yours-fantasy-team-points-after-day-2), where people share their points.

Can anyone help me to find the overall rankings? I'm interested to see my place among the great amount of people watching The International.

Answer (score 3):

### [Here it is](http://www.datdota.com/ti3_fantasy.php)

Saw it on a Na'Vi video. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I'd like to see a table also for fans composed teams (like me), but as @Bloodcount says, it's not yet possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is CyborgMatt's Fantasy Challenge list 
[LINK](http://dota2.cyborgmatt.com/fantasy/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware it is not possible at this moment. I think that the idea of the fantasy teams isn't to compete and that is why it isn't added.